# Terminal auto complete adds aditional \

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash

I am having the issue with my terminal and tab auto complete.
If I try to auto complete using TAB for any file or folder that has a space in the name it is adding an \ before the space.

For example `VirtualBox VMs` will become `VirtualBox\ VMs/`

If I try to auto complete after pressing V then tab.

Any idea whats causing this? thanks

Comment: that' the normal behavior. It is escaping the white spaces. You can type the directory's name inside a single (or double) quote if you do not like to see the \, but auto-complete will not work then.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the spaces being escaped. `\` is the escape character in the bash shell, used in Linux systems, and therefore Ubuntu.

Linux filenames are not really designed to contain spaces, and some other special characters. This is because a lot of Linux/Unix commands use spaces to mark the end of parameters. The escape character is used to stop these special characters having their special meanings, where it isn't desired.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question i'll quote those paragraphs from [Linux journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10954):

> In the good old days when UNIX was young, no one ever would have
>   thought of putting a space in a filename. It simply wasn't done—just
>   as you'd never do that on a DOS or Windows system. Filenames were
>   short, succinct and well-formed, like HW43.DOC.
>
> Most of the Linux command-line utilities and the shells themselves
>   have been designed based on the premise that a space delimits a field
>   value rather than being an acceptable component of a filename.

So to overcome this you should use either an escape character as shown in your terminal, or simply just quote your file with single quote or double quote.

example:

```
cp dir\ 1/ ~/Desktop
```

or

```
cp 'dir 1' ~/Desktop
```

or

```
cp "dir 1" ~/Desktop
```

To read more:

- [Dealing With Spaces in File Names in Command-line (GNU/Linux)](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2014/02/spaces-file-names-command-line/)
- [How to Manipulate Filenames Having Spaces and Special Characters in Linux](http://www.tecmint.com/manage-linux-filenames-with-special-characters/)

You may also find a great interesting answer [for What technical reasons exist for not using space characters in file names?](https://superuser.com/questions/29111/what-technical-reasons-exist-for-not-using-space-characters-in-file-names)

The answer stated some reasons such as:

- Issues in Portability
- Length
- Reserved Characters
- Command-Line Interpretation
- Uniform Resource Locators (URL)

Full details of the answer can be founded in this [link](https://superuser.com/a/484248).